# How to Print Our Own Coumn Name in CSV Response From Solr?

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I want to get the response from solr as CSV Format and write the response as a CSV file. I have done this using CSV Foramt Options in Solr. I have set csv.headerfields as true. The Header Fields are displayed as the field names specified in schema.xml.... Is there anyway to print the Header Fields as user defined field name in Solr?
   For Example I have the field name as "personId" in schema.xml... But in CSV Response I want to print the header field as "Identity Number"... Is it possible to do it in Solr?

Answer (score 1):

Check the field alias feature introduced with [SOLR-1205](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1205) which will allow you to define alias.

Check [Field_alias](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#Field_alias)

Seems Alias doesn't work with CSV Response writer check patch at [SOLR-4671](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-4671)

Comment: I have used this option.... But Not able to get the proper result.. My Code is below...

Comment: SolrQuery query=new SolrQuery("http://127.0.0.1:8984/solr/collection1/select?q=*:*");
query.add("wt", "csv");
query.add("csv.separator",",");
query.add("csv.header","true");
query.add("fl.alias","Number:id");
System.out.println(query.toString());
URL url2 = new URL(URLDecoder.decode(query.toString().replaceFirst("q=", "")));
FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url2, new File("C:/result"+ System.currentTimeMillis() + ".csv"));

Comment: While Executing this code I will get all the field records and No changes in the field name... Is there anything wrong with the code?

Comment: Can I have a small snippet of SOLRJ for CSVWriter(org.apache.solr.internal.csv.writer.CSVWriter)